# Is there a way to easily sum a product of functions depending on another 2D array at each point in a 3D array in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I would like to use Numpy to compute this for each (t,x,y) I give it. Given a grid of points k,l given by `np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10),np.linspace(-1,1,10))`

[image: sum I want to compute for each (t,x,y)]

```
N = 41
k,l = np.linspace(-10,10,N),np.linspace(-10,10,N)
K,L = np.meshgrid(k,l)
def omega(k,l):
  return k/(k**2+l**2+1)
def G(k,l):
  return np.exp(k*l)

omega_vals = omega(K,L)
phi_vals = np.random.uniform(0,np.pi,size=(N,N))
G_vals = G(K,L)

t_vals = np.linspace(0,30000,100)
X,Y = np.linspace(-1,1,100),np.linspace(-1,1,100)

f_vals = np.empty((len(t_vals),len(X),len(Y)))
for k,t in enumerate(t_vals):
  for i,x in enumerate(X):
    for j,y in enumerate(Y):
      f_vals[k,i,j] = np.sum(np.real(G_vals * np.exp(1j*(K*x+L*y - omega_vals*t + phi_vals))))
```

This is my code using loops. The arrays within the sum (e.g. G_vals, phi_vals) are all 41x41 arrays of scalars.

The issue is it's quite slow. Would using arrays help with this since they utilize vectorized operations?

Comment: can you provide a toy example?

Comment: if G, w and phi can accept the k and l as matrices I don't see the problem of just summing

Comment: I've added more context, thank you for your responses

Comment: why are A_vals of `41x41`? the loop added doesn't work with those sizes

Comment: It does, the array within np.real is a sum of 41x41 arrays. But if you know a better approach to this in order to find the sum I attached as an image then that would be great.

Comment: `(K*x+L*y - omega_vals*t + phi_vals` K has 10x10 and omega 41x41 that's not posible

Comment: A [mcve] would be of great help

Comment: @rafaelc I have added some code so it is reproducible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With added dimensions and broadcasting you should be able to get a temporary array that is (41,41,100,100,100) shape.  Then sum the 2 41 dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you so much, that sounds just like what I'm after. Would you be able to show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by making appropriate adjustments based on actual shapes of arrays

```
t_vals = np.linspace(0,30000,100)
X,Y = np.linspace(-1,1,100),np.linspace(-1,1,100)
f_vals = np.empty((len(t_vals),len(X),len(Y)))

x, y, t = np.meshgrid(X, Y, t_vals, indexing='ij')
f_vals = np.sum(np.real(A_vals * np.exp(1j*(K*x+L*y - omega_vals*t + phi_vals))), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would need to sum over at least 2 axes though wouldn't I? Since I want to sum over all the (k,l) i.e. all the elements in the 2d arrays omega_vals, phi_vals, K and L

Comment: `np.sum` takes a tuple for axes, e.g. (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to calculate all values at once, using `expand_dims` on `G_vals` etc, and `np.ix_` on `X,Y,t_vals`), but got

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 12.5 GiB for an array with shape (41, 41, 100, 100, 100) and data type float64
```

My goal was calculate all these values, and then sum on the (0,1) axes  to get the (100,100,100) result.

One option is to reduce the (100,100,100) space.  Another would be to iterate on the the (41,41) dimension, summing values each time.  Or iterate 100 times, making a (41,41,100,100) array each time.

This is typical of numpy tradeoffs.  Many loops take a lot of time, but doing things whole-array style can lead to memory problems.  Often the solution is to compromise, trying to do a 'few' iterations on 'complex' processes.

```
A,B,C=np.ix_(t_vals,X,Y)
G_vals1,K1,L1,omega_vals1,phi_vals1 = np.expand_dims((G_vals,K,L,omega_vals,phi_vals),(3,4,5))

temp = np.real(G_vals1 * np.exp(1j*(K1*B+L1*C - omega_vals1*A + phi_vals1)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7567/3022044735.py in <module>
----> 1 temp = np.real(G_vals1 * np.exp(1j*(K1*B+L1*C - omega_vals1*A + phi_vals1)))

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 12.5 GiB for an array with shape (41, 41, 100, 100, 100) and data type float64
```